# Need to run some time on app service and then consumption, advice?

Tags: azure

Based on the official documentation, app service plan is a better choice when you need your app to run continuously and not start/stop.

Why is this cheaper than the consumption model? What are the primary expense of consumption vs app service plan? Is it the calls to start the function?

I need to run the app continuously for some time (handle data that is there already) and then on a 'on demand' basis (new data coming in). 
What is the recommended way to do this?

Should I run the same app on separate app service (old data) and consumption plans (new data)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean why you need this?  Azure does not support this, could you delete original and redeploy your function to consumption plan?

Comment: I don't know what's the best way to do this. Is it more cost effective to do that or run as consumption from the start?

Comment: Hi, `Consumption plan pricing includes a monthly free grant of 1 million requests and 400,000 GB-s of resource consumption per month.` your app requests are larger than 1 million per month?

Comment: Actually yes. Is there a more clear guide to the pros and cons of consumption vs app service?

Comment: Maybe you should check the [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this cheaper than the consumption model?

No, it depends on your function.

For consumption plan, billing is based on number of executions, execution time, and memory used. Billing is aggregated across all functions within a function app.

The Consumption plan is the default hosting plan and offers the following benefits:

- Pay only when your functions are running.
- Scale out automatically, even during periods of high load.

In the App Service plan, your function apps run on dedicated VMs on Basic, Standard, Premium, and Isolated SKUs, similar to Web Apps, API Apps, and Mobile Apps. App service plan cost please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#how-much-does-my-app-service-plan-cost).

> I need to run the app continuously for some time (handle data that is
>   there already) and then on a 'on demand' basis (new data coming in).
>   What is the recommended way to do this?

Azure does not support change consumption plan to app service plan. According to your scenario, maybe you could create two app plan for two app.

> Is there a more clear guide to the pros and cons of consumption vs app
>   service?

You could read this [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) firstly.

Comment: Do both support the same kind of triggers?

Comment: Yes, triggers is not related with app plan.  Plan is function's OS.